# QuickFix/N logging performance

Tags: c#, performance, quickfix

Has anyone tried creating their own logger in c# as per:

https://github.com/connamara/quickfixn/blob/master/QuickFIXn/FileLog.cs

I am testing this and I don't seem to be able to increase logging speed - there appears to be a finite amount of time taken in getting to:

```
public void OnIncoming(string msg){}
```

Or I am doing something wrong.

In my version, I purely timestamp the message and add to list in memory and write to file later on a background thread. However, the time between log entries appears same as if I wrote straight to disk. So, I am wondering if there is much hidden processing prior to this call.

I have disabled "Crack" - so it is not doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I seems your processing time is not taken by logging, but in your program. Doing an add to a list should be faster than writing it to disk. However if  your program does much processing you will only notice a small difference in the overall performance. You can add a profiler to find where the time is taken.

Comment: Problem is that it is not my code where this is likely to happening - it is part of QuickFix engine.

Comment: If you have no multi threading you can remove the lock (sync_). That is probably the most expensive part of the function.

Comment: Yes I tried that - but I understand lock only cost 50 nano. I am looking for a millisecond